# How to use ActivateRoute's query params map to initiate a navigation map and vice-versa?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular-routing, angular8, angular-router

Following are my route resolvers, routes config and component. I am trying to use the url params to initialize a map (imagine google maps) - does not seem to work as the default lat/lon value is being used always and the param values retrieved from the ActivatedRoute is null.

Url: http://localhost:4500?lat=12&lng=14

Also, the next step will be to update route query params to reflect any panning action on the map (user drags the map and the center coords change)

```
    export class MyComponent {

        lat: number;
        lon: number;

        private map: any;

        constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router) {
            this.route.data.subscribe(data => {
                this.lat = Number(this.route.snapshot.queryParamMap.get('lat')) || 10;
                this.lon = Number(this.route.snapshot.queryParamMap.get('lon')) || 12;
           this.updateUrl();
}

updateUrl() {

    this.router.navigate([], {
        relativeTo: this.route,
        queryParams: {
            lat: this.lat,
            lon: this.lon
        },
        queryParamsHandling: 'preserve',
        // preserve the existing query params in the route
        skipLocationChange: false
    });
}


        public ngOnInit() {
            this.map = new GoogleLikeMap()

            this.map.setCameraGeolocationAndZoom(
                new GeoCoordinates(Number(this.lat), Number(this.lng)),
                14
            );

            this.map.addEventListener('panning', () => {

                this.lat = this.map.geoCenter.lat;
                this.lng = this.map.geoCenter.longitude;

                this.router.navigateByUrl('/?lat=' + this.lat + '&lng=' + this.lng);
            });
        }
    }
```

Trying to access my url as http:localhost:4500
It should append the default lat and lng values to the url if not already present in the url. If the values are already passed to the url via browser, the map should be initialized at that center point.

Comment: appreciate any pointers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this working simply by subscribing to queryParams of the ActivatedRoute.

```
 this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
            this.lat = params.lat;
            this.lon = params.lon;
        });
```